# Intellij IDEA getting remote logs while debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, logging, tail

On my project I have several QA environments, and quite frequently need to debug it. I'm using 'Remote JVM Debug' and it works fine, but  also I want to see logs. I already configured bash script to run tailf over SSH and write it to local file and in debug configuration define local file to see it in log tab of Debug view. But now I'm running these scripts manually and then running debug, and after dubug session I need to stop tailf and disconnect SSH. If I put this scripts to 'Before launch' section, it will wait until this scripts will be completed, and wont start debug itself. I know that I can define run this scripts in background, but I want them to disconnect and terminate when I'm stopping debugging. Is there some solution for this?